# Computer overheats and shuts off after 5-10 min on ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, installation, shutdown, vmware, overheating

I have just tried to install Ubuntu 12.04.3 to my laptop, but i cannot get through the installation, because my computer shuts off. I have windows 7 on it and that runs just fine.
I have installed Ubuntu to a flash driver and tried to run that on my computer, but it still keeps shutting off after a couple of minutes.

The weird think is that i can run ubuntu from VMware player just fine in the background of windows.
I think the problem is that the computer is overheating of the harddrive

Anyone have had this problem? or know how to fix something like this?

Laptop
AMD a8-4500m apu redaeon(tm) hd graphics 1.90 GHz
RAM 8GB
64 bit

Answer (score 0):

For AMD/Intel , run this command in the terminal (uninstall other drivers first):

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-pxpress
```

Then: sudo amdcccle and set the graphics to iGPU and not dGPU and you will see your temperatures falling greatly :)

I recommend to be using Ubuntu 13.10 as it works much better with Hybrid graphics.

Comment: Uninstalled drivers wrote the command, but i cannot get through fast enough. was still running code until computer shut off. Should i rather install 13.10?

Comment: Open your refrigerator and put your computer inside to lower the temperatures as much as possible, now put your computer on a table without touching it (lift it up with something and try to install the drivers) I hope that you now have time to install it, once installed do the instructions below the code and restart and you wont have temperature problems again.

Comment: I shall try, but i am running my computer ontop of an freezing bag. So i do not know how effective this will be

Comment: If the freezing bag is not letting the fans get fresh air you are doing something 0% effective. I hope you can solve your problem. Once you have installed it succesfully please try to give feedback about the resolution and I will give you further intructions to fix broken packages that may be left behind from the OS shutting down unexpectedly.

Comment: Do you know if the problem is the graphic cards or the harddrive? I cannot get through fast enough, and i think im going to change some hardware to get it to work. Will just be using it through VMware until i get a fix

Comment: Overheating cant be due to the hard drive, let it rest for a while and then try.

Comment: So i was in the midle of installation and my computer shut down, and it changed my boot settings to simple bash commands, i had to installa new windows 7 to recover my old one.. im going to try to do the commands on another computer with the ubuntu on the flash drive